Gradle build failing due to non-existing module (that isn't part of the project), how can I fix it?
I mistakenly added a module to a project in Intellij IDEA. I removed the module, I've searched the entire project for any references to the module, I can't find any, yet gradle keeps trying to build it.
How can I fix this? I've tried restarting the gradle daemon, which worked for a while, but when I booted up my laptop today the error is back. It's the bluetooth module that shouldn't be there.

The error is that the folder no longer exists. I cannot figure out how to stop this from being picked up and, as I said, there doesn't appear to be any reference to this module in the project files or in the Intellij settings, project structure, etc.

Deleting the .idea folder in the project root seems to have fixed the issue.
Looks like it was an intellij IDEA issue in the end.
